# When to use a pointer to a pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am reading the following function declaration.

```
static uint8_t prv_read(uint16_t instanceId,
                        int * numDataP, 
                        lwm2m_data_t ** dataArrayP,
                        lwm2m_object_t * objectP)
```

The 3rd argument `lwm2m_data_t ** dataArrayP` is a pointer to a pointer to the following struct.

```
typedef struct _lwm2m_data_t lwm2m_data_t;

struct _lwm2m_data_t
{
    lwm2m_data_type_t type;
    uint16_t    id;
    union
    {
        bool        asBoolean;
        int64_t     asInteger;
        double      asFloat;
        struct
        {
            size_t    length;
            uint8_t * buffer;
        } asBuffer;
        struct
        {
            size_t         count;
            lwm2m_data_t * array;
        } asChildren;
        struct
        {
            uint16_t objectId;
            uint16_t objectInstanceId;
        } asObjLink;
    } value;
};
```

I don't have much experience with pointers to pointers and my question is - is there an obvious reason why the author used a `**` here? Or why would you use one?

Comment: Usually to indicate a matrix; an n-dimensional array.

Comment: @artic sol  Read the function description.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thanks but I'm blind.

Comment: because the function is going to allocate the struct and that `**` will receive the address of it

Comment: if we could see prv_read code then we could tell you without guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a pointer to type `T` when you need to add a level of indirection to an object of type `T`. When type `T` happens to be a pointer, you make a pointer to a pointer.

In your particular situation it appears that the function needs to return several things at once. A common idiom in C for functions providing several results is to pass pointers to results into the function, and let the function set them. Your function provides three results:

- The number of items in `dataArrayP`, through `numDataP`,
- An array of data, through `dataArrayP`, and
- An lwm2m object, through `objectP`

All three results are returned by setting pointers inside the function. The second result happens to be a pointer, i.e. `lwm2m_data_t *`. In order to return a pointer by setting a pointer, a double-pointer must be passed:

```
int numData;
lwm2m_data_t *dataArray;
lwm2m_object_t object;
uint8_t status = prv_read(instanceId, &numDataP, &dataArray, &object);
```

**Note:** Another common use for double-pointers is [defining jagged arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46130032/335858).